# How to include all associated records regardless of filter Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, many-to-many, associations

I have the following models structure in my project

```
class Recipe < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :ingredients, through: :parts, autosave: true
  has_many :tags, through: :tagings, autosave: true
```

We need a functionality to filter all recipes that contains certain ingredients, but include all ingredients for each matched recipe. How this could be done using active record?

For example, if the recipe contains ingredients `onion`, `parsley`, `chicken`, if we look for `chicken`, the recipe should be matched and return all three ingredients. Normally, active record would show only `chicken`.

This is the query we use (disregard tags, they are irrelevant here) :

```
recipes = Recipe.joins(:ingredients).joins(:tags).includes(:ingredients).includes(:author).includes(:tags)

 if recipes_search.ingredients.present?
        ingredients_clause = '%(' + recipes_search.ingredients.map { |i| i.downcase }.join("|") + ')%'
        recipes = recipes.where("LOWER(ingredients.name) SIMILAR TO ?", ingredients_clause)
      end
```

One possible solution is to use subquery to return all the recipe's ingredients like

```
...
select array(select i.name from ingredients i join parts p on i.id = p.ingredient_id where p.recipe_id = r.id) as ingredients 
...
```

This would be used as a column in a result set inside bigger query  where we have `recipes r`. But how to map these ingredients to activerecord association?

Also, is there a cleaner/neater way to do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just to add, the solution should load records eagerly. It can be done normally without using `includes` in the query as I do


      recipes = Recipe.joins(:ingredients).joins(:tags).includes(:author).includes(:ingredients).includes(:tags)

Comment: `Recipe.includes(:author,:ingredients,:tags).where(id: Ingredients.select(:recipe_id).where("LOWER(ingredients.name) SIMILAR TO ?", ingredients_clause))` should do it.

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm. I just needed to add a bit more complexity since Recipe and Ingredient are related using many-to-many (using :through with additional table `parts`). Now it works with just one query. 

Thanks a lot man, this is a solution defintely!

Comment: @engineersmnky according to you, what would be the cleanest way to sort recipes by the number of matched ingredients?
Let's say  I search for recipes containing avocado and tomato. Those which contains only these 2 ingredients should come first. So basically `sort by number of unmatched ingredients asc`. Using similar to only complicates things in this scenario, so it seems there is a need to use multiple queries

Comment: I came up with this in the end